# Android: custom ArrayList doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I have been searching about this problem since three days. Please, help!

I'm trying to make customized ArrayList inside AsynTask, but don't care because it doesn't work outside neither.

First I used setListAdapter, but it was undefined for my class, even my class extends ListActivity. Then, I tried with ListView setAdapter, but it returns nullpointerexception always.

Here's my first code:

```
package Comments;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.helloandroid.R;
import com.example.podcastq.ListActivity;

public class PrepareComments extends ListActivity {

static String titulo;
static String parentid;
static Context contexto;
static ArrayList<String> resultado;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscar_listview);

}

public PrepareComments(Context contexto) {
    super();
    PrepareComments.contexto=contexto;
}


public void SetParams(String titulo, String parentid) {
    PrepareComments.titulo = titulo;
    PrepareComments.parentid = parentid;
}


public void ShowComments() {

    new AsyncTaskSearchName().execute(titulo, parentid);
}

private class AsyncTaskSearchName
extends
AsyncTask<String, String, SubmitResponseResult> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(PrepareComments.contexto);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.cargando);
            dialog.setMessage(PrepareComments.contexto.getString(R.string.obtInfoServer));
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(PrepareComments.contexto, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected SubmitResponseResult doInBackground(String... strings) {

        JoomlaServices oc = new JoomlaServices();

        try {
            SubmitResponseResult sr = oc.getComments(PrepareComments.titulo);
            PrepareComments.resultado = sr.getResult();

            PrepareComments.parentid = sr.getId();

        }  catch (final Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(PrepareComments.contexto,PrepareComments.contexto.getString(R.string.connectionError), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getCause().toString());

                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... responses) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION IN THIS LINE!!

                    ListViewSuggestionAdapter lvSuggestionAdapt = new ListViewSuggestionAdapter(
                            PrepareComments.contexto, R.layout.listview_item_left, PrepareComments.resultado);  

                    lv.setAdapter(lvSuggestionAdapt);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("MI_ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final SubmitResponseResult result) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("MI_ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

With problems in this lines:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION IN THIS LINE!!

                    ListViewSuggestionAdapter lvSuggestionAdapt = new ListViewSuggestionAdapter(
                            PrepareComments.contexto, R.layout.listview_item_left, PrepareComments.resultado);  

                    lv.setAdapter(lvSuggestionAdapt);
```

And here's my second code:

```
package Comments;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.helloandroid.R;
import com.example.podcastq.ListActivity;

public class PrepareComments extends ListActivity {

static String titulo;
static String parentid;
static Context contexto;
static ArrayList<String> resultado;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscar_listview);

}

public PrepareComments(Context contexto) {
    super();
    PrepareComments.contexto=contexto;
}


public void SetParams(String titulo, String parentid) {
    PrepareComments.titulo = titulo;
    PrepareComments.parentid = parentid;
}


public void ShowComments() {

    new AsyncTaskSearchName().execute(titulo, parentid);
}

private class AsyncTaskSearchName
extends
AsyncTask<String, String, SubmitResponseResult> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(PrepareComments.contexto);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.cargando);
            dialog.setMessage(PrepareComments.contexto.getString(R.string.obtInfoServer));
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(PrepareComments.contexto, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected SubmitResponseResult doInBackground(String... strings) {

        JoomlaServices oc = new JoomlaServices();

        try {
            SubmitResponseResult sr = oc.getComments(PrepareComments.titulo);
            PrepareComments.resultado = sr.getResult();

            PrepareComments.parentid = sr.getId();


        }  catch (final Exception e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(PrepareComments.contexto,PrepareComments.contexto.getString(R.string.connectionError), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getCause().toString());

                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... responses) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                                       ListViewSuggestionAdapter lvSuggestionAdapt = new ListViewSuggestionAdapter(
                            PrepareComments.contexto, R.layout.listview_item_left, PrepareComments.resultado);  

                                            PrepareComments.setListAdapter(lvSuggestionAdapt); //UNDEFINED FUNCTION FOR PREPARECOMMENTS IN THIS LINE

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("MI_ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final SubmitResponseResult result) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("MI_ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

With problems in this lines:

```
ListViewSuggestionAdapter lvSuggestionAdapt = new ListViewSuggestionAdapter(
                            PrepareComments.contexto, R.layout.listview_item_left, PrepareComments.resultado);  

                                                PrepareComments.setListAdapter(lvSuggestionAdapt); //UNDEFINED FUNCTION FOR PREPARECOMMENTS IN THIS LINE
```

My xml definition for the ListView is:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:longClickable="false" >
        </ListView>
```

Thanks!

EDITED: LogCat

```
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at Comments.PrepareComments$AsyncTaskSearchName$3.run(PrepareComments.java:141)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-31 22:10:08.995: E/AndroidRuntime(283):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why are you referencing the list view ,as you have already extended ListActivity, you can set adapter using getListView().setAdapter();

Comment: I don't know why, but even I extend ListActivity, I can't use ListActivity methods. Using getListView() it says "undefined method" too :(

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ListView lv = (ListView)PrepareComments.this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

instead of

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to initialize `lv` with ListView inside onProgressUpdate

**NOTE :** no need to use `runOnUiThread` inside `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` because these method called on UI thread then we can access or update UI element without using runOnUiThread

Comment: It says nullpointerexception too. 

When I comment this line this exception dissapears, for that I know the problem is in this line :(

Comment: @user1870231 : in which line u have issue

Comment: In this one: ListView lv = (ListView)PrepareComments.this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Comment: which problem u have in this line because this syntax is perfectly working on my end

Comment: @user1870231 : where is PrepareComments.java:141 line in your code

Comment: I edited my post with LogCat Nullpointerexception. I don't know why this line give me problems, I have used similar lines above all my code. I tried to put this line out the AsyncTask and out the PrepareComments class, but the error persists at the same line.

Comment: PrepareComments is called in onCreate() of MainActivity
PrepareComments pc = new PrepareComments(this);
pc.SetParams(myItemData.getActualTitle(pos), parentid);
        pc.ShowComments();

Comment: @user1870231 : change your code as http://pastebin.com/87rWfCL5 and let me known it's working or not

Comment: With the new code there aren't exceptions, but the list doesn't show anything. I have tried to set Log.i in onProgressUpdate and Log doesn't show anything in Logcat neither, for that I think onProgressUpdate code is not executing :(